# Angular 4. Как обращаться к параметрам во вложенных маршрутах

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Добрый день. Подскажите, как получать параметры из вложенных маршрутов.
Когда я делаю так:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

            this.route.firstChild.data.subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data.name);
        });


    }
```

То при первой загрузке я получаю корректное значение а когда начинаю кликать по ссылкам с другими вложенными маршрутами значение не обновляется.
И как правильно получать параметры из вложенных маршрутов, доки перечитал официальные там это не раскрыто....

Comment: попробуй `<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>` и вынеси `onActivate(componentRef){
    componentRef.route.data.subsribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    });
}`

Comment: я сделал но: onActivate(componentRef){
        console.log(componentRef);
    } возвращает обьект компонента который отрендерен в роутер отутлет. http://joxi.ru/bmo0KbOtMo48R2 . Там нет связанного с обьектом роута.

Comment: думаю вы неправильно настроили дочерние роуты

Comment: const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: HolderComponent, data: {name: 'root'},
        children: [
            {path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {name: 'base'}},
            {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: {name: 'register'}},
            {path: 'contacts', component: ContactsComponent},
            { path: '**', component: Page404Component }
        ]
    },

];  http://joxi.ru/L21XBJjT6VM4xm

Comment: Так ошибку пример выше выкидвал или нет?

Comment: да, это все этот код, там все просто как велосипед, это учебные семплы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65908/discussion-between-artsiom-and--).